# Adding a user defined row to a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

So me and my group are working on dataset we named "lhm" with the Lisbon Housing Market. We are trying to build a tool that will allow for people to upload a house they want to sell it using the function add_selling_house.
Some variables, like country, are predefined the other will be the at the user choice.
Everything seems to work well until the method of adding the new house (sellinghouse) as a new row of the lhm dataset, because we are using the dataset before.
Does anyone has a clue of how to solve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the dataset and the work that you've already done?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you're looking for, but here is a function that takes a dataframe and various arguments to return a new dataframe with passed arguments appended in a single row.

If you had a dataframe like this:

```
lhm = pd.DataFrame([["Blue House", "Portugal", 400000], ["White House", "Portugal", 200000]], columns = ["Name", "Country", "Price"])
lhm

Output:
          Name   Country   Price
0   Blue House  Portugal  400000
1  White House  Portugal  200000
```

You can define easily define a function that takes specific arguments relating to the columns in your dataframe. For example:

```
def add_selling_house(data, name, price, country = "Portugal", **kwargs):
  # Define your other arguments for this function

  # Use provided args to create a series. 
  # Ensure order matches however you defined it in the dataframe
  s = pd.Series([name,country, price], index = data.columns)

  # Append series to passed dataframe and return
  return data.append(s, ignore_index = True)

add_selling_house(lhm, "New House", 10000, "Spain")

Output:
          Name   Country   Price
0   Blue House  Portugal  400000
1  White House  Portugal  200000
2    New House     Spain   10000
```